# TransitionGroup takes 486 seconds to remove 500 components

Tags: react-transition-group

I'm using `<TransitionGroup/>` and `<CSSTransition timeout={2000}>...` and all transitions are set to take `2000ms` in CSS.

If I add and then remove a small number of entries, it takes roughly 2000ms for `onExited()` to be called as expected.

But with 500 entires, it takes TransitionGroup 48 seconds (chrome) or 486 (!!!!) seconds (firefox) before `onExited()` is called on the last element after removing 500 elements.

Why is that? This makes it useless for my use-case.

I've created a [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/transitiongroup-component-iu7nz) which is just a modification of the [TransitionGroup example](https://codesandbox.io/s/00rqyo26kn) from the [doc](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group). There is a button to add 100 items at a time and a a "Remove All" button that prints to the console how long it took from beginning the removal until both `onExiting` and `onExited()` are called on the last element.

This sounds to me like a bug, but if there is something I can do differently, that would be great.

If it really is a bug I guess I could do it with pure CSS, but right now, I don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong in the way TransitionGroup was used. I've created:

[TransitionGroup takes 486 seconds to remove 500 components · Issue #599 · reactjs/react-transition-group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/issues/599)

where I've also outlined why in the code I think this happens, and a half-assed, incomplete attempt at fixing it.